# "User has uploaded files to your contest" or "User has uploaded files for your contest"?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

I want to show this text on the email that'll be sent to the contest creator. It will be performed whenever a user submits a file to the content.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

> User has uploaded **contest files**

**Contest** [can function as an adjective](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-adjective-for/contest.html), and it will sound just fine in the sentence.